# Bootstrap 4 scroll to sticky nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having profound difficulty getting my bootstrap 4 navbar to stick to the top of the page when scrolled past. I must have tried 10 different codes I found on Stackoverflow and over google sources, but none have been successful.

Here is the html:

```
<!--new navbar-->
<nav name="navbar" class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse" data-toggle="sticky-onscroll" role="navigation" id="navbar">
    <a class="" href="#">
        <img class="mini-logo" src="miniNest.png" alt="Responsive image">            
    </a>
    <div class="center-nav ">
        <button class="hidden-sm-up navbar-toggler-right navbar-btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="btn-group mr-2 collapse navbar-collapse alignm" id="navbarSupportedContent"  aria-label="First group">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-primary btn-xlg">blah blah <br><sub class="sub">credentials</sub></button>                            
            <button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-primary btn-xlg">blah</button>                            
            <button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-primary btn-xlg">blah</button>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-primary btn-xlg">blah</button>
        </div>
    <!--button group-->
    </div>
    <!--center-nav-->
</nav>
<!--new navbar-->
```

This is what I thought to be the most likely to be successful, but still scrolls past.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if( $(this).scrollTop() > 150 ) {
    $(".navbar").addClass("fixed-top");
  } else {
    $(".navbar").removeClass(""fixed-top);
  }
});
```

Did I do something wrong building my navbar?

Comment: `$(".navbar").removeClass(""fixed-top);` should be `$(".navbar").removeClass("fixed-top");`

Comment: Have you checked for JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: @RickyDam Thanks. That was a typo when asking the question. It is right in the program and still not working.

Comment: @Blazemonger I just checked and I am getting errors opening each of my javascript files. 
    Access to Script at 'file://' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS 
    policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Haha...That is the best error of web development. CORS... I guess you js files and your html are not on the same server (possibly not the folder on the same server) right ?   What are you using ? Apache ? IIS ?  xampp ? wamp ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, it like exactly what you want without any cose of JS, just edit classes to put your own class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
          <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your sample uses BS3. Can you upgrade it to BS4 - that would give you a much better chance of anwering the OP's question (and getting an upvote from me, as I am struggline with the same...)

Answer (score 0):

The `sticky-top` class does the work for you.
But keep in mind that this utility isn’t fully supported in all browsers. [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/position/#sticky-top)

**Example:**

```
<header class="sticky-top">
    <nav>
        ...
    </nav>
</header>
```